# Building a kitchen appliance: stream, surf, touch screen, boot fast

Tags: gui, touch-screen

I want to build an appliance for the kitchen. It is supposed to play music (files, streams, CDA), surf the web (recipe sites!), maybe play video (files and streams) display todays agenda during breakfast.

Because I do not want it to run 24/7, it should boot up really fast. I am thinking about a small SSD for the OS.

I also want to use a touch screen.

I will probably use NetBSD or Linux (not sure yet).

It really should get the feel of an appliance like a car GPS system or a smart phone.

Now here is the question: Is there some kind of interface that can be operated by touch screen (on screen keyboard?) and that can be tweaked to what I want to do with it?

Bonus question: Did you build such a system yourself? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [MeeGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeeGo), which is designed for touchscreen enviornments.

**Working state**: The Linux Foundation canceled MeeGo in [September 2011 (archived blog)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140422132159/https://meego.com/community/blogs/imad/2011/whats-next-meego) in favor of [Tizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizen), which Intel then joined in collaboration with Samsung--all former pages at meego.com will now redirect to Tizen.org

MeeGo has a fork named [Mer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mer_(software_distribution)).

Comment: how about android?

Comment: @phunehehe - that should work too, but I suspect MeeGo's Debian base will make this kind of development easier